Disabling auto-save
I wrote code to replace the standard WORD document save with a macro execution. But there was a problem, the macro is executed automatically once in a while and, accordingly, interferes with working with the document.
My code:
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Sub Document_Open()
    Call LogSet App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Doc = ThisDocument Then 
        Application.Run "save" 
        Cancel = True 
    End If 
End Sub

I assume that the problem is related to the auto-save of the document, but I can't figure out how to disable auto-save only in this document, and not all at once.
It should work as standard so that when a user tries to save a document, the standard save should be canceled and a macro should be launched.
How can I configure the beforeSave function to be executed only when users try to save a document manually, and so that the function does not respond to autosave of the document?

Why do you define an Answer variable and never use it?

I forgot to delete the variable, it was previously used for MsgBox. It has already been removed from the code

This solution helped - completely disabling auto-save when opening a book and turning it back on when exiting. Updated code:
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Sub Document_Open()
    Call Log
    
    With Application.Options
        .SaveInterval = 0
        .SaveNormalPrompt = False
    End With
    
    Set App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Doc = ThisDocument Then
        Application.Run "save"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Close()
    With Application.Options
        .SaveInterval = 10
        .SaveNormalPrompt = True
    End With
End Sub

The only problem with this solution is that if the user writes text in another document at the same time, autosave will not work and in an unforeseen situation you will need to re-write.
